# Skype- How to answer a call using commands

Tags: skype

Is there a way to code something, and the moment I run the code the call will be answered?
I need this because I am planning to assign this coded program to my keyboard, so when I play a game and someone calls me, I'll be able to answer It using a hotkey instead of getting out of the game to answer it.
Thank you :P

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there's hotkey support in Skype already. [link](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12025/what-are-hotkeys-and-how-do-i-use-them)

[image]

Comment: I prefer C#, though I want to be able to answer a question using anything, batch files / C# programs / C++ programs etc